# How to stop network manager from connecting to other networks

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, fedora

I am facing intermittent wireless network connection. I have already specified a SSID for network manager to connect to. But whenever the network is down, the network manager will attempt to connect to other networks, causing multiple prompts of request for network password to appear. How do I prevent the network manager from connecting to other networks and still allow it to automatically connect to the specified network when it is up again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Do you download a lot? watching HD/Netflix movies?
- Do you shutdown the router at end of the day?

If yes to first question AND|OR no to second question, your wireless router is getting HOT and failing.

You can put the router over a small fan that will keep air circulated and keep it cool.

Also, your using too much bandwidth that your router can handle (I guess at least 3 wireless devices connected). Buy a Gigabit router that can handle the overload.

Finally, check for trojan/virus that can insidiously take up bandwidth without your knowing it.

Comment: My answer is no, I don't download a lot (no movies, seldom youtube) and yes, I do shutdown my router at the end of the day when I go to bed. How hot is hot? I do feel my router is hot, but not burning hot. I may have up to 4 wireless devices connected. No, I don't think it is a virus issue since I am experiencing the connection problem on all devices. Anyway +1 for the advice on changing a router (I may consider that) though you haven't answer my question.